# Django Crispy Form class not creating an object

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

## My Issue

I'm writing a Django application where I want users to input addresses via a form. I want users to be able to add additional address fields if they want to enter more than the default number of addresses (3). I have been struggling to figure out how to accomplish this.

### First Attempt

The first way I tried was simply using JavaScript to add fields on the click of a button, but when I do this the data from the added field is not submitted. I get the data from the three fields hard-coded into the form class, but the additional fields are not submitted, I assume because they are not part of the form class that I created.

### Current Attempt

Since I couldn't use data from fields added using JavaScript, I'm now trying to create a dynamically-sized form in Python. My general thinking is to pass the number of location fields to the class and then use that number to create the form. I know my looping mechanism for creating the form itself works because I tested it with hard-coded numbers. However, I did that without overriding the `__init__` function. To pass a number to the form, I need to override this function. When I do this, it seems that no form object is created and I have no idea why. Here is a sample of my code:

#### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Row, Column, ButtonHolder, Button

class EnterLocationsForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        num_locations = kwargs.pop('num_locations')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i in range(1, num_locations + 1):
            name = 'location{}'.format(i)
            exec("{} = {}".format(
                name,
                "forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
                                 attrs={'placeholder': 'Address {}'.format(i)}))")
            )
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    helper.form_method = 'POST'
    helper.form_show_labels = False

    helper.layout = Layout()
    for i in range(1, num_locations + 1):
        helper.layout.append(Row(
            Column('location{}'.format(i), css_class='form-group'),
            css_class='form-row'
            ),)

    helper.layout.append(ButtonHolder(
                 Button('submit', 'Go', css_class='btn btn-primary'),
                 Button('add', '+', css_class="btn btn-success"),
                 css_id="button-row",
             ))
```

#### views.py

```
from .forms import EnterLocationsForm

location_count = 3

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EnterLocationsForm(request.POST, num_locations=location_count)
        ...
    else:
        form = EnterLocationsForm(num_locations=location_count)
        # if I write print(form) here, nothing is printed

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Any tips on why this isn't creating a form object would be much appreciated! If there's a way to make my first approach work that would be great too.

Comment: Looks like you want formsets. Note that there might be some indentation issues in your form's code snippet (is this really what your code looks like ???), and that "nothing is printed" doesn't mean your form is not created - there might be others reasons why it's doesn't make it to your `sys.stdout`. Also, don't use `exec`, there are much better (and saner) ways to dynamically add fields to a form.

Comment: Formsets are exactly what I needed, thanks for sending me in the right direction! Some of the indentation might be off, I copied the code in segments and some of the original indentation got messed up; I tried to fix things but I might have missed some. Thanks again!